# Sharing .exe with people who do not have ODBC Driver installed?

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

I've created an Executable that utilizes pyodbc to connect to SQL Server. I need to share this executable with colleagues who have not downloaded the ODBC driver on their computers which causes the executable to fail to open.

I understand if they were to download the ODBC driver I could adjust the executable to detect the driver of the computer each time to avoid this issue. However, not everyone I share this executable with is technical so I would like to avoid having them install the ODBC driver.

Is there a way to create an executable that connects to SQL Server that does not require the user to have an ODBC driver installed on their computers?

```
try:
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
except:
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows includes an ODBC driver named "SQL Server" as part of its standard installation so every Windows machine has it. It is targeted to older versions of SQL Server so it doesn't support some of the newer features in the latest releases, but if your needs are fairly basic it might suffice.

Comment: I tried adjusting my code to reflect that (I've edited my question to show this) but still am not having any luck