# Not able to run a python exe (not python installed, not odbc driver installed...)

Tags: python, sql-server, tkinter, exe, pyodbc

Problem:

1. I would like to automatize one daily task avoiding the excel usage and this have as final objective centralizing the data in *SQL Server*. For that I have created a *TKinter GUI with Python*.
2. Once I have validated the python script in my PC, I have created an *exe with pyinstaller*.
3. After testing the exe in one quality technician PC (not python installed), I have detected an error message in the cmd related to the *absence of installation of the pyodbc driver*.

Question / Help request:
Do we have any way to run this exe, without the necessity of installing python in all the PCs? I would like to avoid this scenario.

If we have any library or package available for this... I am not being able to identify which is!

Error Message:

[image]

Code:
[image]

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62876345/2144390

Comment: You can use powershell I guess. It's usually installed already and contains libs for SQL server. But it's more of console app so you don't get nice gui etc

Comment: @siggemannen - Interesting idea. Perhaps [Python.NET](https://pythonnet.github.io/) might allow us to work with SQL Server using .NET client libraries instead of ODBC.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/929). Although it's one on Linux, it will guide you to the correct path. Also post the full error message.

Comment: @Gord Thompson, @siggemannen, FYI, the OP wants to use ```pyodbc```. She is asking how to package ```pyodbc``` with ```PyInstaller```.

Comment: Try adding `--collect-all pyodbc` when executing `pyinstaller`.

Comment: Regards the duplicity of this publication, I would like to clarify that the other ticket didn't resolve anything to the creator and also to me. The proposed solution didn't work.

Comment: Yes sorry. I forget to complement my message with further details. Now I have attached the cmd message and the involved python code. In addition, I will come back with feedback about the results of the --collect-all comand, hope it works

Comment: Hi @acw1668 , unfortunately your suggestion didn't work also. It still continue displaying the same error "No module named 'pyodbc'" Do you have any additional ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works for me.  I can find the `pyodbc` module inside the generated executable.

Comment: @acw1668 Did you write the next in the cmd: pyinstaller --onefile --collect-all pyodbc program_name.py? Just to ensure that I am writting properly the command you suggest to us.

Comment: I used `pyinstaller -F --collect-all pyodbc my_script.py` which is basically the same as yours.

Comment: What version of `PyInstaller` you are using?  Actually `pyinstaller -F my_script.py` works as well and I am using `PyInstaller` version 5.7.0.

Comment: Hi @acw1668 sorry for the delay. My PyInstaller version is 5.7.0 and I still continue having the same issue.